# how to click the submit button in the webpage

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on my vb.net application to put the textbox and button as i'm using the webbrowser in my form. I have got a problem with getting the element id from the webpage. When I put the text in the textbox and when I click on the form button, I will get an error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Here is the html source:

```
<button value="1" class="_42ft _4jy0 _11b _4jy3 _4jy1 selected" type="submit">Post</button>
```

Here is the code I use:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("_42ft _4jy0 _11b _4jy3 _4jy1 selected").InvokeMember("click")
```

Do you know how I can click the button in a webpage who have got the class id?

Answer (score 0):

Your button has a class, not an id, but your code is trying to find it by ID. change your button to:

```
 <button value="1" id="_42ft _4jy0 _11b _4jy3 _4jy1 selected" type="submit">Post</button>
```

or if you want to get it by class, use getElementsByClassName(""), but this returns a collection of all the buttons with that class. That means you have to know if there are more than 1 with the class name. You get the button by its index, so:

```
 var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("_42ft _4jy0 _11b _4jy3 _4jy1 selected");
 btn[0].click();
```

0 is the first one, 1 is the second and so on

Comment: im sorry i can't change the code because it's not my website. so can you please give me the correct source to use `getElementsByClassName("")`? i tried to use `WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByClassName("_42ft _4jy0 _11b _4jy3 _4jy1 selected").InvokeMember("click")` but GetElementsByClassName is not a member of system.windows.forms.htmldocument

Comment: can you please give me the correct source to use getElementsByClassName("")?

Comment: thank you very much for that, but the code you post is sound like c++ or something like that. can you please update your source that i can use it for vb.net?

Comment: it is javascript. you are trying to submit an HTML button, right? submitting the button via JS calls your vb code behind (whatever you want done on submit). You don't click a button with vb. You can call a sub with vb--not sure what what you are trying to do, sorry.

Comment: Yes I do, but I can't change the code because i'm using facebook. I'm using vb.net code so can you plz change your code?